# pass variable from .php file to external.html file with JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
/inAseperateFile.php
```

I am creating a dynamic date variable in an external .php file.

***i.e.***

```
  $date = new DateTime();
  echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

I need to grab it, and print it onto an external .html page; with JavaScript.

```
/DifferentHTMLfile.html
```

***i.e.***

```
<span class="modified-timestamp" id="printDateVar"></span>
```

Here is my latest attempt with ajax (from within '`/DifferentHTMLfile.html`') :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'inAseperateFile.php',
        success: function(date){
            alert(date);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Adyson Exactly

Comment: No-spex you'd have to call `inAseparateFile.php` using AJAX, and get back the echo'd value

Comment: Now...you haven't actually asked us a question. You've tagged ajax already, so I guess you're aware of its existence. What problem are you facing, exactly? You should be able to fairly easily research how to make a basic ajax request in this scenario. Have you looked into it at all?